# Database Design -- Which one is better approach?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, rdbms

***Database Design | Approach 1:***

[image]

In this approach, I am maintaining two different tables for different type of entities and having the relationships with other tables as per the image above.

***Database Design | Approach 2:***

[image]

In this approach, I am having single table for both the entities(In future can be added more) and having the referential integrity as highlighted in blue.

Which is the better approach to go with, if i consider best database design practices and ORM implementation(Two entities per table with usage of discriminator)? Please suggest.

Thanks

Comment: learn table inheritance

Answer (score 0):

You are asking the wrong question here.  Which is the better approach is not a simple question, in order to answer this we would need to know many different things about the situation you are trying to solve including

1. Does the solution actually work for what you want
2. Which solution is easier to understand.
3. Are the requirements going to change in the future
4. How often do the requirements change.
5. Do you actually need the more complex of the two solutions

The real answer is to look at your situation and determine what makes sense to solve the problem and try to anticipate any problems that could arise in the future, keep in mind though that some instances will simply not arise, then go with what makes sense to you/your team.  Sorry for the somewhat vague answer but this is one of the situations the answer truly is: "It depends."

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But my question is in terms of the database design practices, like proper usage of referential integrity, ORM implementation(two entities per entity table with the usage of discriminator), etc...